# How to run Type-a-Number Challenge sample app?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

- I downloaded the type a number challenge from https://developers.google.com/games/services/downloads/#samples
- I imported this to Eclipse
- I added BasegameUtils and play services lib to the project
- I renamed everything correctly, no errors
- I signed to developer console and added a new game Type a number... like in tutorials
- I linked the app with correct package
- I looked for my SHA1 android debug keystore and used this code
- I added the 6 sample achievements and 2 leaderboards
- I copied the resources for ids.xml
- I added the app_id to the manifest
- I added test accounts (only mine account)
- I exported my application with exlipse export wizard with the same debug keystore and I checked that the two keystores was the same.
- I send the MainActivity.apk to my phone in three ways:

  1. First (easier) Enabled usb debugging and when i can browse phone storage I paste the .apk file
  2. Enabled usb debugging and then i typed to cmd the adb -d install .apk
  3. Third Enabled usb debugging and from eclipse ran the app.

And in the same way the apk was installed and I can run it BUT every time when i want to sign in I get the:

> The application is incorrectly configured. Check that the package name and signing certificate match the client ID created in Developer Console...
>   Also if the application is not yet published, check that the account you are trying to sign in with is listed as a tester account. See logs for more information.

Can somebody help me wht is the problem?

The logs only send the same messages in the troubleshooting site and I tried everything form here and these are correct.